# How Can I Make An Odd Shaped Icon into a "Circle"?

Tags: html, css

**How Can I Make An Odd Shaped Icon "Circle"?**

**The issue:** I have 2 icons on a site that are irregularly shaped. I'm adding a `padding`, `background-color`, and `border-radius` to them. At some screen sizes the background-color looks like a circle, but at others, it starts to look like an oval (which I don't want).

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/gv2wne9o/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/83x111" alt="icon" />
</div>

<div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/83x111" alt="icon" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    border-radius: 100%; 
    background-color: #555555; 
    padding: 10%;
}
```

Comment: You want to make it square? Then why put a border-radius at all?

Comment: I want it to be "Square" so the 100% Border-Radius will make it perfectly round

Comment: @CSSApprentice then it is a circle, not a square...

Comment: I used the quotes to signify I didn't mean Square. More so "Square" like the framing term.

Comment: @CSSApprentice I think you should use circle, so everybody undertands. Using "square" needs interpretation and I don't think everybody will interpret it the same way you do.

Comment: Agreed! I'll post as a new question

Comment: @CSSApprentice don't! ou can edit this one (see the "edit" link at the bottom of your post under the tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gv2wne9o/1/ (applied to one of the two icons)

Just setting a border-radius is not going to do it in this case. And you need to set left and right padding without top and bottom padding, since your icon's dimensions are oval-shaped (83*111).

Assuming your icon is an inline-block element, you can use the following code to determine exactly how much left and right padding to add until the width of the element is equal to the height.

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var padding = 0;

while(img.offsetWidth < img.offsetHeight){
    img.style.paddingLeft = (++padding)+"%";
    img.style.paddingRight = padding+"%";
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a ton, and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/h8pgyga6/)

```css
img{
  border-radius:0px;
  background-color: #555555; 
  padding: 10%;
  }
```

EDIT:

Define Square: a plane figure with four equal straight sides and four right angles.

You do not have 4 equal sides therefore you're using a RECTANGLE.

Comment: That's a rectangle :(

Comment: Yes, but the icons I spoke of in the question aren't 111x111. They are 83x111

Comment: Then that's not SQUARE is it, its RECTANGLE. it doesnt take a  mathematician. Define Square: a plane figure with four equal straight sides and four right angles.  FOUR EQUAL SIDES.

Comment: Hence why I asked the question. How can I make my rectangle square?

Comment: Then your answer is no.. unless you're some kind of shape bending mathematician.

Comment: I'm sure there's some basic Javascript/jQuery that can ensure equal height and width.

Answer (score -2):

Bro, You are putting "border-radius:100%" and what else do you expect? border-radius must be "1% - 5%" for any proper use at website. When you provide anywhere with such a high value as "border-radius:50%" and above it will be oval and "at 100%" it(div) will be a ***circle***. What's the issue?

```
border-radius:5px
```

try to put the border-radius as such, and you will get a proper square with non-pointed end-points! Hope, that solves the issue! Happy coding!

Comment: The height and width values would make that a rectangle, and not a square :/

Comment: Nopse, however higher width or height you take, the more you increase border-radius, the more curvature would be provided and if height=width=x it will become square, and if height!=width, it will become oval. So put the border-radius value too much less (nearly 15%), and dont underestimate the power of "border-radius", the curvature goes bending the whole length of the div, not only corners at higher value!